# get all child element of a form in J.S

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

how can i get all child element(like radio,checkbox,select,text,...) within a form and make them blank using javascript. My form has many other elements like table,div etc. but i dont want to changes on these other element.

Any suitable idea to get these child element(form element) through the form name(frmlist) or form id(frmlist) and make them blank. Actually i have no idea previously that how many elements are there in form and what are the names/ids of these element.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Do you have an specific need for it to be JS? Is the reset button not enough? <input type="reset" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Example Form:

```
<form name="data_entry" action="#">
    Company Name: <input type="text" name="company_name">
    Select Business Type: <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="1"> Manufacturer
    <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="2"> Whole Sale Supplier
    <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="3"> Retailer
    <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="4"> Service Provider
    Email Address: <input type="text" size="30" name="email">
    Keep Information Private: <input type="checkbox" name="privacy">
    <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset();">
    <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">
</form>
```

Example Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < frm_elements.length; i++) {
    field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
    switch (field_type) {
    case "text":
    case "password":
    case "textarea":
    case "hidden":
        frm_elements[i].value = "";
        break;
    case "radio":
    case "checkbox":
        if (frm_elements[i].checked) {
            frm_elements[i].checked = false;
        }
        break;
    case "select-one":
    case "select-multi":
        frm_elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

From [Using Javascript to Reset or Clear Form](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml).

Comment: Hello Michael Robinson frm_elements is what ? is form name ?

Comment: @BajrangLal: It's explained well in the tutorial I linked to

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we forget about old solutions. Why not ditch the javascript here and use:

```
<input type="reset" value = "CLEAR all"/>
```

see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/FQa7t/)

Comment: Actually when page is submited using php on same page then the reset button is not working as reset. I tried it.

Comment: That would indicate a flaw in [the rest of] your code, I suppose.

Comment: @Kooilnc - This would work if all of the input elements were "blank" as per his original question. Unfortunately, type="reset" resets the form to it's original state which means that if a field already had a value in it originally (not entered by the user), it wouldn't be "blank."

Comment: @Francois: I understand that. But the OP asked "how can i get *all child element(like radio,checkbox,select,text,...)* within a form and make them blank using javascript"

Comment: @Kooilnc - "Blank" (or empty) isn't back to default (which is what the reset button does.)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It would be as simple as doing:

```
$(':input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: Francois Deschenes ! how can i use it ?

Comment: Go to jQuery's website and download it. Once downloaded, add a `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the HEAD of your page. You'll then need to add a function to an element's event to trigger the function. For example, if you want a ekement to trigger the action when you click it, you'd want `$(function() { $('#buttonID').click(function() { ... }); });` where #buttonID is the ID attribute value of the element and ... is the code above. Of course you'd want the code in a <script> tag.

Comment: @Jeff - I'm not forgetting select. All SELECT elements' values will be set to "" (an empty string). The `.not()` defines the types of :input not to include. jQuery defines :input as any input element including select, textarea, checkboxes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to get all forms elements

```
 function getAllFormFields(node)
   {
    var allFormFields = new Array;
    var x = node.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    allFormFields.push(x[i]);
     var y = node.getElementsByTagName('option');
     for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    allFormFields.push(y[i]);
     return allFormFields;
      }
```

i have been viewing quiksmode.org, the function idea is from quirksmode.org

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to add a reset button to the form (per KooiInc's answer), it will return all controls to their default value with no scripting at all:

```
<input type="reset">
```

and you're done.

If you **must** use script (heaven knows why), call the form's [reset](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767677) method:

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset()">
```

The other part of your question is how to get all the controls in a form when it also contains other elements (forms must contain a block element as a child to be valid). HTML form elements have an [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) collection that is all the controls in the form. It is a simple property access, no functions or filtering required:

```
var allControls = form.elements;
```

Simple enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in case anybody came searching, a quicker oneliner code in his situation would be:

```
$('#frmlist')[0].reset()
```

Note the array accessor `[0]`. The element returned is the frmlist form which you then call `reset()` on. This resets all the fields in the form to their default value.